# Problem with multiple subdomains conflict : Ubuntu django nginx+apache mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, mod-wsgi

I have installed my django application on one of my subdomains .. **subdomain1.mydomain.com**  using nginx+apache mod_wsgi on Ubuntu.
It was working fine until I installed another django application on **subdomain2.mydomain.com**.Now  **subdomain1.mydomain.com** started pointing to application installed on **subdomain2.mydomain.com**

Here is my nginx and apache conf..
*nginx configuration for subdomain1.mydomain.com:*

```
upstream  subdomain1_backend  {
    server  127.0.0.1:8080;
}  
server {  
    listen       80;  
    server_name  subdomain1.mydomain.com www.subdomain1.mydomain.com;  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://subdomain1_backend;
    }  
}
```

*nginx configuration for subdomain2.mydomain.com:*

```
upstream  subdomain2_backend  {
    server  127.0.0.1:8080;
}  
server {  
    listen       80;  
    server_name  subdomain2.mydomain.com www.subdomain2.mydomain.com;  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://subdomain2_backend;
    }  
}
```

*apache conf for subdomain1.mydomain.com*

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>  

 ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
 ServerName  subdomain1.mydomain.com
 ServerAlias www.suddomain1.mydomain.com

 DocumentRoot "/srv/webapps/subdomain1.mydomain.com"

 WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/webapps/subdomain1.mydomain.com/conf/app.wsgi  
 WSGIDaemonProcess www.subdomain1.mydomain.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=15 processes=2 maximum-requests=10000    
 WSGIProcessGroup www.subdomain1.mydomain.com  
 <Directory /srv/webapps/subdomain1.mydomain.com/app/>  
   Order deny,allow  
   Allow from all  
 </Directory>  
 ...   
 </VirtualHost></code>
```

*apache conf for subdomain2.mydomain.com*

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>  

 ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
 ServerName  subdomain2.mydomain.com
 ServerAlias www.suddomain2.mydomain.com

 DocumentRoot "/srv/webapps/subdomain2.mydomain.com"  
 WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/webapps/subdomain2.mydomain.com/conf/app.wsgi  
 WSGIDaemonProcess www.subdomain2.mydomain1.com user=www-data group=www-data threads=15   processes=2 maximum-requests=10000    
 WSGIProcessGroup www.subdomain2.mydomain.com  
 <Directory /srv/webapps/subdomain2.mydomain.com/app/>  
   Order deny,allow  
   Allow from all  
 </Directory>  
 ...   
 </VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have you cut out the interesting bit from the Apache confs? Where's the `ServerName`/`ServerAlias` stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see, your both django applications works on the same address:port

By default nginx is not forwarding "Host:" header.

You must add this line to you nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```